Trait bounds in Fn traits
I may be missing something simple, but I am having a hard time convincing the Rust compiler that this writer let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file); can be used in the F: Fn(Write) -> Result<()> trait bound. For example, the below works:
fn write_using_writer<F>(file: &Path, f: F) -> Result<()> 
where
    F: Fn(&mut BufWriter<File>) -> Result<()>,
{
    let file = File::create(file)?;
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);
    let _ = f(&mut writer)?;
    writer.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

fn write_to_file(data: MySerializableStruct) -> Result<()> {
    let path = Path::new("./output.json");
    
    write_using_writer(path, |writer: &mut BufWriter<File>| 
            serde_json::to_writer(writer, data).map_err(|e| Error::SerdeJson { err: e }))
}

I wanted to generalize this for some Writer, i.e. I want the consumer at a call site to use some Writer without necessarily knowning its specific implementation.
In my attempt to placate the Rust compiler, I did this:
fn write_using_writer_a<W, F>(file: &Path, f: F) -> Result<()> 
where
    W: Write,
    F: Fn(W) -> Result<()>,
{
    let _ = ensure_dir(file)?;
    let file = File::create(file)?;
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);
    let _ = f(&mut writer)?;
    writer.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

The compiler, however, gives me this error message:
mismatched types
expected type parameter `W`
found mutable reference `&mut std::io::BufWriter<std::fs::File>`

What am I missing?
I tried replacing
 F: Fn(W) -> Result<()>,
with
  F: FnMut(W) -> Result<()>,
but it didn't make any difference.

What you have attempted to write says "callers of write_using_writer_a will provide a function f that takes parameter type W of their choice, but regardless of that choice I will then call f with &mut BufWriter<File>".

As soon as I read your comment, I realized that the signature made no sense. Thank you! As @drewtato pointed out, what I really wanted is for fn write_using_writer_a() to accept Fn which takes a Write; the implementation of fn write_using_writer_a() should provide the "Writer" to use.

Per your words, you "really want" to use a caller-provided W: Write, yet provide the closure with &mut BufWriter<File>. So I don't understand your goal.

I reworded the question for clarity. I know that the original question caused confusion as to what I was trying to accomplish. Hopefully, it is now clear, and the second block was code was my attempt to solve the problem (incorrectly, as some pointed out).

What you're trying to say is that the caller of write_using_writer_a can provide a closure that accepts some type W that they choose, but that whatever they have chosen, you will pass a &mut BufWriter<File> instead. This obviously can't work.
If you want to avoid naming the BufWriter<File>, what you really want to say is that the caller of write_using_writer_a should provide a closure that accepts some type W that you choose and that they only need to know that W implements Write. This is currently not possible in stable Rust, but can be done on nightly using Impl trait in type aliases:
#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]

use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::{ BufWriter, Result, Write };

pub type MyWriter = impl Write;

pub fn write_using_writer_a<F>(file: &Path, f: F) -> Result<()> 
where
    F: Fn(&mut MyWriter) -> Result<()>,
{
    // let _ = ensure_dir(file)?;
    let file = File::create(file)?;
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);
    let _ = f(&mut writer)?;
    writer.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

Playground

This is very cool; magic, I would say. By far, the easiest solution, but I need to read up on how it actually works (thank you for the link -- and the solution). For my app, using the nightly compiler is not a problem, but this may be a non-starter for others, in which case I would go with the solution provided by @drewtato. I wish I could accept both solutions.

The only thing to be gained from replacing BufWriter in the signature is to weaken your API guarantees when write_using_writer_a is public. If you don't need to do that, leave it as BufWriter. If you do, then read on.
You don't actually want write_using_writer_a to be generic over W. That would mean the caller can decide which W to use, but in your case, you need to accept a function that takes a specific writer, but don't want the caller to know which one.
There is syntax for this already in Rust, which looks like this:
fn write_using_writer_a<F>(file: &Path, f: F) -> Result<()>
where
    F: for<W: Write> Fn(W) -> Result<()>,

This is called a higher ranked trait bound (HRTB), but currently it only works for lifetimes. Instead, what you can do is create your own type that only provides the API you want—the Write trait—and have the function take that.
pub struct WriteWrapper<'a>(&'a mut BufWriter<File>);

// implement all methods so that all behavior is preserved
impl Write for WriteWrapper<'_> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.0.write(buf)
    }
    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.0.flush()
    }
    fn write_vectored(&mut self, bufs: &[std::io::IoSlice<'_>]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        self.0.write_vectored(bufs)
    }
    fn write_all(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.0.write_all(buf)
    }
    fn write_fmt(&mut self, fmt: std::fmt::Arguments<'_>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        self.0.write_fmt(fmt)
    }
}

fn write_using_writer_a<F>(file: &Path, f: F) -> Result<()>
where
    F: Fn(WriteWrapper) -> Result<()>,
{
    let file = File::create(file)?;
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);
    f(WriteWrapper(&mut writer))?;
    writer.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

Now you can make write_using_writer_a public, and changing the internal BufWriter will not be a breaking change.

Fun fact: this function does use an implicit HRTB for the lifetime on WriteWrapper. It is equivalent to this:
fn write_using_writer_a<F>(file: &Path, f: F) -> Result<()>
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(WriteWrapper<'a>) -> Result<()>,


I really liked your answer, for a couple of reasons. (1) consider if I actually need to weaken the API guarantees: by making it explicitly BufWriter<File> it hints the user at the call site just how the Write is implemented. So far I have two types of callers: serde_json::to_writer which takes Write (in my example) and writing bytes to a file, e.g. writer.write_all(..), both of which obviously write to files, which justifies BufWriter in a signature. However, I was (theoretically) thinking how I could generalize this.

and (2) the solution itself is no magic (see the one provided by @Jmb), but it is explicit, so it is easy to see how it works. I have encountered higher ranked trait bounds in some APIs before, so I am aware of lifetimes.

If I may have another question to enhance my knowledge. In your desugared HRTB function, the signature is saying, "I promise that the reference held by BufWriter will be valid for as long as the caller is using it in the Fn (closure)", isn't it? And the reason it is not necessary in this case is due to Rust's elision rules?

@madisonmuir 1) Yes, and this is the weakest promise you can make about a lifetime. 2) Yep.

As the other answer has stated, this is probably not what you want. But there are scenarios where calling a function with a generic function is necessary.
To do this, we need to create a trait that will serve as the function:
trait MyFun {
    fn my_f<W: Write>(&self, w: W) -> Result<(), Error>;
}

Then we can implement this trait for the "functions" we send into the function:
struct ExampleFun;

impl MyFun for ExampleFun {
    fn my_f<W: Write>(&self, w: W) -> Result<(), Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}

The actual function using this:
fn write_using_writer_a<F>(file: &Path, f: F) -> Result<(), Error> 
where
    F: MyFun
{
    let file = File::create(file)?;
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);
    let _ = f.my_f(&mut writer)?;
    writer.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

And an example main:
fn main() {
    write_using_writer_a(Path::new("/test.txt"), ExampleFun).unwrap();
}

playground
